# Do I have to make allowances for Inno setups on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, inno-setup

We've got an ancient of days VB6 app which sometimes needs to be updated and installed on our user's machines.  We've begun using Inno, and especially InnoIDE, to make the setup.exe, to get this onto our user's PCs.  However, I'm wondering about 64-bit Windows, and Inno setups.  We've got a couple of machines in-house, which are 64-bit versions of Windows 7 Professional.  I've successfully installed our app, using the setup from Inno, onto a 32-bit Windows XP machine.  Can I use the same setup on our 64-bit Windows 7 machines?  Will it put the .exe into the C:\Program Files (x86)\ directory structure automatically, or do I have to make allowances for 64-bit versions of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is only 32-bit, then Inno will automatically take care of doing everything correctly.

*Only* if your app is mixed or 64-bit do you need to do anything special as rushman says.
There is a very good [section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_32vs64bitinstalls.htm) in the help file that explains the changes needed.

If you're installing any 64-bit device drivers, the calls to most newdev and setupapi entry points will fail with error code 0xE0000235 (ERROR_IN_WOW64). Those calls only work when invoked from 64-bit code, and Inno doesn't compile 64-bit installers yet. You may work around by using [pnputil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by adding a 64-bit stub executable, or by switching to [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Answer (score 1):

For 64-bit INNO intallations you generally only need to add one setup section directive and, obviously, add the 64-bit versions of DLL's and EXE's to the compiled installer.

The setup section directive is:

ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

Comment: In this case, there is no 64-bit versions of either DLL's or EXE's.  I'm just wondering if I have to make sure that INNO will put the EXE and associated DLL's under the C:\Program Files (x86)\ folder area on the user's machine, or if I have to do something about making sure that happens.

Comment: If there are no 64-bit versions of DLL's or EXE's, then I think you should install as a 32-bit application. If you do not provide the Setup directive in my answer, INNO will assume a 32-bit installation and {pf} will map to C:\Program Files (x86)\.